# Convert a String payload to a POJO in Mule using Java Component

Tags: java, mule

I have the following flow:

```
    <flow name="load-flow" doc:name="load-flow">
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="/Users/andre/Desktop/Feeder" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
    <file:file-to-string-transformer doc:name="File to String"/>
    <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <component class="transformer" doc:name="Java"/>
</flow>
```

and a POJO Person

```
private String name; private String surname; private String email;
```

I input a cv file then take it to string. i then want to read the payload into a java component and then map the values of the csv file to a POJO Person. how can this be done? how do you read the string payload into a java component and how would i map it to the POJO Person

Answer (score 0):

Use the datamapper transformer. It can map to and from many data formats.

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Datamapper+User+Guide+and+Reference